# How to manually call custom PropType validators in React v16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a use case where I need to write a custom React `PropType` validator. Within that checker I want to do two things: 1) validate that the prop names inside the object, which are dynamically generated, are all md5 hashes, and 2) validate the "shape" of the object connected to each prop.

Question #1 I have figured out; #2 is eluding me a bit. Here's some code to illustrate:

Say I have an object like this:

```
{
  key1: {
    byHash: {
      '<some md5 hash>': { ... }
    }
  },
  key2: {
    byHash: {
      '<some md5 ash>': { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

When checking this object I want to make sure that the keys are indeed md5 hashes, and then I want to ensure the correctness of the keys and their values in each of the objects assigned to `key1` and `key2`. Let's say, in addition, I've created a validator function like so:

```
const validObjShape = PropTypes.shape({
  someString: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  someBoolean: PropTypes.bool
});
```

Then I write my custom validator function:

```
const validCustomProp  = (props, propName, componentName) => {
  const obj = props[propName];

  if (!isObject(obj)) {
    return new Error(
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '`of type `' + typeof obj + '` supplied to ' +
      '`' + componentName + '`, expected an object.'
    );
  }

  if (isEmpty(obj)) {
    return null;
  }

  forEach(obj, (v, k) => {
    const isMD5 = (/[a-fA-F0-9]{32}/).test(k);

    if (!isMD5) {
      throw new Error(
        //eslint-disable-next-line
        'Invalid dynamic key on `' + propName + '`. All keys ' +
        'on this object should be md5 hashes, but we found `' + k + '` instead.'
      );
    }
  });

  // Here I want to somehow validate each object on `obj`. Something like:
  // forEach(obj, (v, k) => { 
  //   const err = validObjShape(props[propName], k, componentName);
  //   if (err) {
  //     // throw some err...
  //   }
  // }

  return null;
};
```

My question -- as noted in-line above -- can I use the `validObjShape` that I created above to validate the shape of the objects nested within `obj`. I think that this calling of a validator fn directly will be disallowed in v16 of React (see [this post](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html)). So how can this now be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `PropTypes` **directly from React** is deprecated - not the use of `PropTypes` themselves.

As it says in the docs, [declaring `PropTypes` is fine](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html#declaring-proptypes-is-still-fine), just use the [prop-types](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) library instead.

So,

```
const apiShape = React.PropTypes.shape({
  body: customValidator,
  statusCode: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
}).isRequired;
```

simply changes to

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const apiShape = React.PropTypes.shape({
  body: customValidator,
  statusCode: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}).isRequired;
```

And the `customValidator` doesn't have to change.

You can verify this yourself in the source: [ElementCreation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ae430b79139777b74167b124719b3dc311aa5294/src/isomorphic/ReactEntry.js#L26) => [ElementValidation in DEV mode](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L243-L297) => [Validating prop types](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L297) => [calling checkPropTypes](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElementValidator.js#L229) which has simply been moved [here](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/checkPropTypes.js)

React strongly believes in type safety and deprecating `PropTypes` altogether seems very unlikely. It is still present in the [docs (from the master)](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/docs/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.md)

#### Calling validator functions as you mentioned is now deprecated too

[Note from the docs](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#difference-from-reactproptypes-dont-call-validator-functions)

> This is new behavior, and you will only encounter it when you migrate from React.PropTypes to the prop-types package.

So the following is deprecated

```
  Object.keys(props[propName]).forEach(k => {

    // const v = props[propName][k];
    const isMD5 = (/[a-fA-F0-9]{32}/).test(k);
    if (!isMD5) {
      return new Error(
        'Not an md5'
      );
    }

    return validObjShape(props[propName], k, componentName);
  });
```

Instead use `checkPropTypes`:

```
const validObjShape = PropTypes.shape({
  someString: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  someBoolean: PropTypes.bool
});

const validCustomProp  = (props, propName, componentName) => {

  Object.keys(props[propName]).forEach(k => {

    const v = props[propName][k];
    const isMD5 = (/[a-fA-F0-9]{32}/).test(k);
    if (!isMD5) {
      return new Error(
        'Not an md5'
      );
    }

    PropTypes.checkPropTypes({ [k]: validObjShape }, { [k]: v }, propName, componentName);

  });


  return null;
};
```

Comment: @fraxture You've updated your question. Does my answer need an update as well?

Comment: Nope, it's good. Thank you! I'm just waiting to confirm that the solution works for me.

Comment: Manas, one thing I think may need updating. I have I think been able to get this working. However, in my use of `checkPropTypes` so far it does not return a value. So, in your code above `objShapeInvalid` would always be `undefined`. `checkPropTypes` seems to fire an error on its own if there's a mismatch. That also seems to conform with the sample code in the docs you linked`: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#proptypescheckproptypes . So maybe update your answer?